# AngularJS SmartTable & ASP.NET mapping error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to accomplish asp.net mapping of the current tableState from SmartTable.

I use ASP.NET MVC 5.

My angularjs call look like this:

```
 usersService.getUsers({
                start: start,
                number: number,
                tableState: tableState
            }
        ).then(function(result) {

        });
```

My queryString parameters look like this:

```
number:10
start:0
tableState:{"sort":{"predicate":"location","reverse":false},"search":{"predicateObject":{"location":"gfdgd","service":"gfdgd","company":"gd","fullname":"john"}},"pagination":{"start":0,"number":10}}
```

And of course i try to map in asp.net the query information. My controller action look like this:

```
   public JsonResult GetUsers(SmartTableRequestModel request)
        {
            return GetJsonResult(new
            {

            });
        }
```

And the models which i try to bind at are the following:

```
 public class SmartTableRequestModel
    {
        public SmartTableQueryModel TableState { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; } // number is well-binded

        public int Start { get; set; } // the start is well-binded too
    }

 public class SmartTableQueryModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("sort")]
        public SmartTableSortModel Sort { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("search")]
        public SmartTableSearchModel Search { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("pagination")]
        public SmartTablePaginationModel Pagination { get; set; }
    }

 public class SmartTableSortModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("predicate")]
        public string Predicate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("reverse")]
        public bool Reverse { get; set; }

    }
```

And so on ...

But i didn't get anything mapped in the tableState model. The TableState property from my SmartTableRequestModel object is always null.

Thanks for your following help,
Razvan

Comment: I assume you are using asp.net MVC. Can you please post some more details like what version of MVC you are using?

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for that. I use ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Have you tried using TypeConverters or model binders? See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my getUsers was a httpget method and you can't pass a model to a httpget method.

So i changed my resources to match a httppost call.

```
    {
        getUsers: { url: ci.domainPub + '/Management/GetUsers', method: 'POST', action: 'getUsers'},
    },
```

And in controller the action will be:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetUsers(SmartTableRequestModel request)
        {
            return GetJsonResult(new
            {

            });
        }
```

And with this mechanism you can post the smartTable plugin's tableState without any processing and filter/order based on that on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending request data something like below.

```
{"request" :{"TableState": {"sort":{"predicate":"location","reverse":false},"search":{"predicateObject":{"location":"gfdgd","service":"gfdgd","company":"gd","fullname":"john"}},"pagination":{"start":0,"number":10}}},"Number":10,"Start":1}
```

Comment: This won't work of course. The binding isn't working that way.

Comment: Did you try or just guess?

Comment: I tried, but i was sure that it won't work. The problem is that my getUsers was a httpget method and you can't pass a model to a httpget method and expect it to map.

Comment: Any chances to convert it to http post?